# How to use std::sort with opaque data types efficiently?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I'm working on an SDK which defines interfaces like

```
class FooIter
{
    // Move to the next foo, return false if there is none.
    virtual bool Move() = 0;

    // Return a pointer to the current foo.
    virtual const void* GetFoo() = 0;

    // Get the size of a 'foo', which is a fixed-size POD.
    virtual size_t GetFooSize() = 0;

    // Get a comparator for foos.
    virtual const FooComparator* GetComparator() = 0;
};

class FooComparator
{
    virtual int compare(const void* first, const void* second) const = 0;
};
```

So basically, a foo is an opaque type that I can treat as a fixed-length binary buffer + and associated ordering function.

Now, I want to sort these foos before passing them back to client code. There may potentially be **many** foos, so I'll have to implement external sorting, but I'd like to use std::sort to sort the initial runs.

I was thinking I would allocate a buffer of size N * FooIter::GetFooSize(), fill it with foos using FooIter, and then sort it with std::sort before writing it to disk.

I can start by writing an iterator class

```
class FooBufferIter
{
public:
    FooBufferIter(const void* fooAddr, int fooSize) : m_fooAddr(fooAddr), m_fooSize(fooSize) {}

    FooWrapper operator*() {return FooWrapper(m_fooAddr, m_fooSize);}

    FooBufferIter operator++() {return FooBufferIter(m_fooAddr + m_fooSize, m_fooSize);}

    // All other needed iterator methods.
private:
    const void* m_fooAddr;
    int m_fooSize;
};
```

and a wrapper class for foo memory

```
class FooWrapper
{
public:
    FooWrapper(const void* fooAddr, int fooSize) : m_fooAddr(fooAddr), m_fooSize(fooSize) {}

private:
    const void* m_fooAddr;
    int m_fooSize;
};
```

My understanding is that std::sort will use std::swap to rearrange the elements in the sequence. My issue is I can't see how to specialize std::swap on FooWrapper to perform the swap efficiently (most importantly, no dynamic allocation). I could swap byte by byte, but that also seems inefficient.

Another way of doing this would be to sort a parallel sequence of pointers into my Foo array, but I don't want to do that, since in practice, the foos will likely be quite small, so the parallel sequence could use just as much memory as the foo sequence, and I want to maximize the number of them I can sort at a time.

There's also good ol' qsort which is probably more suited to this kind of thing, but I'm not sure how to convert the FooComparator object into a function pointer (there may be multiple implementations of FooComparator).

Or is there a better way of going about this? I don't really want to write my own sort implementation, although it probably wouldn't be *too* hard.

Comment: I don't see why a byte swap would be bad. You need to rearrange objects so you will need to copy memory (or pointers to them). In large it really depends on the implementation of the opaque type. If they are efficiently swappable, you are fine.

Comment: @pmr - I might just be overthinking it, but the ideal way to swap them would be to have a temporary buffer large enough to hold a foo, memcpy a into it, memcpy b into a, then memcpy the temporary buffer into b. If you do it byte-wise, you need to do n byte swaps in a loop, where n is FooIter::GetFooSize()

Comment: Yes, but as I said: If you have to do an operation you need to do it. And the temporary buffer would be static (it has too, because you cannot swap data of different types). You probably can do a (word-wise XOR swap)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm] but if this would really make it faster remains to be seen.

Comment: Well, I think the actual answer is to implement sort myself, thereby allowing the safe use of once-allocated buffer for the temporary. But it really is premature optimization now that I've thought about it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build a buffer of void*, sort them, then produce the output buffer.

As a first step.  Because easy.  Then write everything else and look for performance bottlenecks.

As a next step, I would see if internal sorting with full type info can be done.  Because optimal.

Failing that, a pod block pseudo reference iterator with a specialized swap.  With tomfoolery for small med and big if performance tests justify further optimization so it sorts pointers for big and data for small.

But start with KISS and do the parts that have to be hard first.

Comment: Having different implementations based on FooIter::GetFooSize() may be the way to go...