# How to efficiently use `std::sort` for an opaque data type with a run-time record length?

Tags: c++, sorting, iterator, c++20

### Question

I want to use `std::sort` for an opaque data type with a run-time record length. Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15047037/1202808) to a similar question.

### Attempts

I have tried indirectly sorting record pointers and indices, but these methods have terrible cache locality because the comparisons need to access randomly distributed rows of the dataset.

I also tried falling back to the `C` functions `qsort` which allows for run-time record length. This is better, but it requires a callback function for the comparison. This has two drawbacks, 1) performance suffers compared to using a lambda which can be inlined, and 2) the interface ergonomics are poor because you (probably) have to create a structure to hold a functor for the comparison.

### Possible Idea

The previously mentioned answer suggested a,

> pod block pseudo reference iterator with a specialized swap,

but did not give any hints about how that might work.

### Summary

To summarize, I want a way to call `std::sort` passing in a lambda for the comparison for an array of opaque data types with run-time record length as the following code demonstrates,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using std::cout, std::endl;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    // We have 100 records each with 50 bytes.
    int nrecords = 100, nbytes = 50;
    std::vector<uint8_t> data(nrecords * nbytes);

    // Generate random data for testing.
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint8_t> d;
    std::mt19937_64 rng;
    std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), [&]() { return d(rng); });

    int key_index = 20;
    auto cmp = [&](uint8_t *a, uint8_t *b) {
        int aval = *(int*)(a + key_index), bval = *(int*)(b + key_index);
        return aval < bval;
    };

    // How can I call std::sort with run-time record length?
    // std::sort(data.begin(), ...)
    return 0;
}
```

### Iterator Attempt

I attempted to write an iterator based on the previous suggestion, but I have not been able to get it to compile yet. My *iterator-foo* is sub-par and I feel like I am making a conceptual error.

Here is the code,

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

struct MemoryIterator {
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = uint8_t *;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using reference = value_type&;

    MemoryIterator(value_type ptr, size_t element_size)
        : ptr_(ptr)
        , element_size_(element_size) {
    }

    reference operator*() {
        return ptr_;
    }

    MemoryIterator& operator++() {
        ptr_ += element_size_;
        return *this;
    }

    MemoryIterator& operator--() {
        ptr_ -= element_size_;
        return *this;
    }

    MemoryIterator operator++(int) {
        auto tmp = *this;
        ++(*this);
        return tmp;
    }

    MemoryIterator operator--(int) {
        auto tmp = *this;
        --(*this);
        return tmp;
    }

    MemoryIterator& operator+=(size_t n) {
        ptr_ += n * element_size_;
        return *this;
    }

    MemoryIterator operator+(size_t n) {
        auto r = *this;
        r += n;
        return r;
    }

    MemoryIterator& operator-=(size_t n) {
        ptr_ -= n * element_size_;
        return *this;
    }

    MemoryIterator operator-(size_t n) {
        auto r = *this;
        r -= n;
        return r;
    }
    friend bool operator==(const MemoryIterator& a, const MemoryIterator& b) {
        return a.ptr_ == b.ptr_;
    }

    friend difference_type operator-(const MemoryIterator& a, const MemoryIterator& b) {
        return a.ptr_ - b.ptr_;
    }

    friend void swap(MemoryIterator a, MemoryIterator b) {
    }

private:
    value_type ptr_;
    size_t element_size_;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int nrecords = 100, nbytes = 50;
    std::vector<uint8_t> data(nrecords * nbytes);

    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint8_t> d;
    std::mt19937_64 rng;
    std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), [&]() { return d(rng); });

    int key_index = 20;
    auto cmp = [&](uint8_t *a, uint8_t *b) {
        int aval = *(int*)(a + key_index), bval = *(int*)(b + key_index);
        return aval < bval;
    };

    MemoryIterator begin(data.data(), nbytes);
    MemoryIterator end(data.data() + data.size(), nbytes); 
    std::sort(begin, end, cmp);

    return 0;
}
```

It complains that it cannot compare two `MemoryIterator`'s which is true -- it needs to use the comparison function.

### Compilation Error

```
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-16/bin/../include/c++/v1/__algorithm/sort.h:533:21: error:
      invalid operands to binary expression ('MemoryIterator' and 'MemoryIterator')
            if (__i >= __j)
                ~~~ ^  ~~~
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-16/bin/../include/c++/v1/__algorithm/sort.h:639:8: note:
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__introsort<std::_ClassicAlgPolicy, (lambda at
      sort0.cpp:92:16) &, MemoryIterator>' requested here
  std::__introsort<_AlgPolicy, _Compare>(__first, __last, __comp, __depth_limit);
       ^
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-16/bin/../include/c++/v1/__algorithm/sort.h:699:10: note:
      in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__sort<(lambda at
      sort0.cpp:92:16) &, MemoryIterator>' requested here
    std::__sort<_WrappedComp>(std::__unwrap_iter(__first), std::__unwrap_iter(__last), _...
```

Comment: What *measurable* performance problems do you have? How far off from your *performance goal* are you?

Comment: Here is a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76124368/1202808) of mine that goes into more detail on some of the measurements I have done. For my particular end application, sort is the bottleneck and fast-enough is not on the horizon.

Comment: What is the `size_t element_size` parameter of your iterator for if not for `nbytes` and why do you pass in `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: And (if I'm not way off) any `sort` implementation must also compare the iterators in one way or another because it shall only swap `a` and `b` if `a < b && &a >= &b`. So it must compare the addresses which are represented by the iterators. Other than that I think the iterator approach looks very sensible.

Comment: @chrysante Fixed the iterator constructors -- should have passed `nbytes`.

Comment: And after you supply comparison operators for your iterator, I think you also need a proxy reference type for which you define `swap` **and `operator=`** to actually perform the swaps.

Comment: `std::sort()` [requires](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort#Parameters) a [random access iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator). `MemoryIterator` is [not](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator#Requirements) random access iterator, so it's not clear why you expect `std::sort()` to work with it.

Comment: @Evg You are of course right, it should be **declared** random access via the `iterator_category` typedef. Functionally however it obviously **is** random access. Pointing that out would have been more helpful.

Comment: @chrysante No, functionally it is *not* random access, take a look at requirements referenced above.

Comment: Sure, you're correct. It's missing some operator overloads, in particular comparison operators (and `operator[]`, but I think libc++'s `std::sort` doesn't care about that). I guess what I meant is it can be easily made random access.

Comment: @chrysante It can. And then what's the question?

Comment: @I assume the question is _how_ and then how to make `std::sort` work with it, which actually is pretty tricky.

Comment: @chrysante Not that tricky after it is made a truly random access iterator (which _is_ somewhat tricky), I guess.

Comment: @Evg The tricky part is actually to implement the `reference` and `value_type` of the iterator. But sure, it's no sorcery and actually straight forward with the right idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the ingredients we need to make `std::sort` work the way you desire:

### Proxy references

Proxy references are user defined types mimicking C++ references (as much as possible). Through them the elements in the byte array are actually moved around by `std::sort`.

Note that for a more robust implementation that perhaps does more than `sort`, you would also supply a `ConstRecordReference`, akin to `iterator` and `const_iterator` in standard library containers.

```
struct RecordReference {
    explicit RecordReference(void* data, size_t element_size):
        _data(data), _size(element_size) {}
    
    RecordReference(Record&);
    
    RecordReference(RecordReference const& rhs):
        _data(rhs.data()), _size(rhs.size()) {}
    
    /// Because this represents a reference, an assignment represents a copy of
    /// the referred-to value, not of the reference
    RecordReference& operator=(RecordReference const& rhs) {
        assert(size() == rhs.size());
        std::memcpy(data(), rhs.data(), size());
        return *this;
    }
    
    RecordReference& operator=(Record const& rhs);
    
    /// Also `swap` swaps 'through' the reference
    friend void swap(RecordReference a, RecordReference b) {
        assert(a.size() == b.size());
        size_t size = a.size();
        // Perhaps don't use alloca if you're really serious
        // about standard conformance
        auto* buffer = (void*)alloca(size);
        std::memcpy(buffer, a.data(), size);
        std::memcpy(a.data(), b.data(), size);
        std::memcpy(b.data(), buffer, size);
    }
    
    void* data() const { return _data; }
    
    size_t size() const { return _size; }
    
private:
    void* _data;
    size_t _size;
};

/// After the definition of Record (see below):

RecordReference::RecordReference(Record& rhs):
    _data(rhs.data()), _size(rhs.size()) {}

RecordReference& RecordReference::operator=(Record const& rhs) {
    assert(size() == rhs.size());
    std::memcpy(data(), rhs.data(), size());
    return *this;
}
```

### Class type to represent your records

It is rather annoying that we even need this. We need it because libstdc++'s `std::sort` implementation (and probably any implementation) creates some stack allocated copies of our values, so we need to supply something sensible for our iterators `value_type` that actually represents a record.

We provide an inline buffer to avoid heap allocations up to a reasonable size. You can tune the `InlineSize` parameter to the expected size of your records.

```
struct Record {
    static constexpr size_t InlineSize = 56; 
    
    Record(RecordReference ref): _size(ref.size()) {
        if (is_inline()) {
            std::memcpy(&inline_data, ref.data(), size());
        }
        else {
            heap_data = std::malloc(size());
            std::memcpy(heap_data, ref.data(), size());
        }
    }

    Record(Record&& rhs) noexcept: _size(rhs.size()) {
        if (is_inline()) {
            std::memcpy(&inline_data, &rhs.inline_data, size());
        }
        else {
            heap_data = rhs.heap_data;
            rhs.heap_data = nullptr;
        }
    }
    
    ~Record() {
        if (!is_inline()) {
            std::free(heap_data);
        }
    }
    
    void* data() { return (void*)((Record const*)this)->data(); }
    
    void const* data() const { return is_inline() ? inline_data : heap_data; }
    
    size_t size() const { return _size; }
    
private:
    bool is_inline() const { return _size <= InlineSize; }
    
    size_t _size;
    union {
        char inline_data[InlineSize];
        void* heap_data;
    };
};
```

It seems however that at least libc++'s `std::sort` implementation only ever creates one object of this type at a single time. This means that we could preallocate a `thread_local` buffer on the stack to hold that single object. This way we prevent heap allocations for any record size, at the expense of relying on an implementation detail of `std::sort` and potentially creating *runtime* errors in future builds, so I would not recommend this. Also this renders the types useless for many other algorithms.

### And finally your iterator class

As noted in the comments it needs to have relational comparison operators defined (to satisfy the *random access iterator* requirements or just because `sort` logically needs them).

It exposes our `Record` and `RecordReference` types via the `value_type` and `reference` typedefs.

```
struct MemoryIterator {
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = Record;
    using pointer = void*;
    using reference = RecordReference;

    MemoryIterator(pointer ptr, size_t size)
        : ptr_((char*)ptr)
        , size_(size) {
    }

    reference operator*() const {
        return reference(ptr_, size_);
    }

    reference operator[](size_t index) const {
        return *(*this + index);
    }

    MemoryIterator& operator++() {
        ptr_ += size_;
        return *this;
    }

    MemoryIterator& operator--() {
        ptr_ -= size_;
        return *this;
    }

    MemoryIterator operator++(int) {
        auto tmp = *this;
        ++(*this);
        return tmp;
    }

    MemoryIterator operator--(int) {
        auto tmp = *this;
        --(*this);
        return tmp;
    }

    MemoryIterator& operator+=(size_t n) {
        ptr_ += n * size_;
        return *this;
    }

    MemoryIterator operator+(size_t n) const {
        auto r = *this;
        r += n;
        return r;
    }

    MemoryIterator& operator-=(size_t n) {
        ptr_ -= n * size_;
        return *this;
    }

    MemoryIterator operator-(size_t n) const {
        auto r = *this;
        r -= n;
        return r;
    }
    
    friend bool operator==(const MemoryIterator& a, const MemoryIterator& b) {
        assert(a.size_ == b.size_);
        return a.ptr_ == b.ptr_;
    }
    
    friend std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const MemoryIterator& a, const MemoryIterator& b) {
        assert(a.size_ == b.size_);
        return a.ptr_ <=> b.ptr_;
    }

    friend difference_type operator-(const MemoryIterator& a, const MemoryIterator& b) {
        assert(a.size_ == b.size_);
        return (a.ptr_ - b.ptr_) / a.size_;
    }

private:
    char* ptr_;
    size_t size_;
};
```

[Here you can find a live demo of the code.](https://godbolt.org/z/aah7z9zcv)

Comment: Thanks @chrysante, the hints in the comments and this answer are very helpful. As a side note, on my platform (Mac, arm64), using the heap for the `value_type` subsumed using the stack. For small sizes (`<=32`), I could not measure a difference and for larger sizes, the heap was more efficient. My guess is that the heap provides better locality (a good allocator will reuse the same chunks) and adjusting the stack, while being virtually free itself, has cache implications for local variables.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. It's interesting that heap allocations are faster than stack allocations. May I ask by how much?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some simple proof-of-concept code that seems to work.  It works by constructing a second vector of `struct`s pointing at the 'records' in the original data and then sorts it.

`std::sort` can then be persuaded to do the right thing by crafting a suitable copy constructor and copy assignment operator.  I don't know if this is optimal, and the code could certainly be factored better.

OK, here we go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout, std::endl;

struct sortable_record
{
    sortable_record (int record_size, uint8_t *data, uint8_t *swap_buf) :
        record_size (record_size), data (data), swap_buf (swap_buf) { }

    sortable_record (const sortable_record &other)
    {
        data = other.swap_buf;
        operator= (other);
    }

    sortable_record &operator= (const sortable_record &other)
    {
        record_size = other.record_size;
        swap_buf = other.swap_buf;
        memcpy (data, other.data, record_size);
        return *this;
    }

    int record_size = 0;
    uint8_t *data = nullptr;
    uint8_t *swap_buf = nullptr;
};

int main() {
    int nrecords = 10, nbytes = 50;
    std::vector<uint8_t> data(nrecords * nbytes);

    // Generate (simplified!) data for testing.
    for (int i = 0; i < nrecords; ++i)
    {
        std::fill (&data [i * nbytes], &data [i * nbytes] + nbytes, 'z' - i);
        *(&data [i * nbytes] + nbytes - 1) = 0;
    }

    // Populate vector of sortable_record's
    std::vector<uint8_t> swap_buf (nbytes);
    std::vector<sortable_record> sort_me;
    sort_me.reserve (nrecords);
    for (int i = 0; i < nrecords; ++i)
        sort_me.emplace_back (nbytes, &data [i * nbytes], swap_buf.data ());
    
    int key_index = 20;
    auto cmp = [key_index](const sortable_record &a, const sortable_record &b) {
        uint8_t aval = a.data [key_index];
        uint8_t bval = b.data [key_index];
        return aval < bval;
    };

    std::sort (sort_me.begin(), sort_me.end(), cmp);

    for (int i = 0; i < nrecords; ++i)
        std::cout << (const char *) &data [i * nbytes] << endl;
}
```

Note that bad things will happen without `sort_me.reserve (nrecords);`, so the code building `sort_me` should all be bundled up in a nice factory function.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mizIJbGpBD2jggIR)